# Codename one, Styling the side Menu

Tags: codenameone

How can i style the side menu, I created it using this tutorial [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ipr1eXsu9L4), I want ot make it transparent and insert a label with a logo

please see below images on how i would like it to look like.

**How it looks now**

[image]

**How i would like it to look**

[image]

**How i would like it to look when opened**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To style the side menu, modify the `SideNavigationPanel` UIID in your theme.

To add the logo, you can do something like this

```
Toolbar t = new Toolbar();
form.setToolbar(t);
t.setTitle("tayary");
Label logoLabel = new Label(logoImage);
logoLabel.setTextPosition(Label.BOTTOM);
logoLabel.setText("label text here");
logoLabel.setUIID("SideMenuLogo");
t.addComponentToSideMenu(logoLabel);
```

Add the `SideMenuLogo` UIID to your theme, change `Alignment` to `Center`, and adjust the Top and Bottom margins.

To underline commands, modify the background in `SideCommand` UIID in your theme. It should be of `Type`: `IMAGE_TILE_HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_BOTTOM`. For the image, you can use any borderBottom image in your theme (If you don't have one, create any border using Image Border Wizard, and use its borderBottom image).

You can check [this demo](https://github.com/codenameone/RestaurantDemo) for a working a example.

Comment: I would also suggest invoking `new Toolbar(true)` so it will be transparent on top of the application background.